# How to select specific list items in a list and add a line through property when mouse is hovering/clicking over them in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that adds a line through property to a list whenever the mouse hovers or clicks over a list item.

My HTML:

````
``` <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul class="noteList">
        <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
        <li>Jello</li>
        <li>Spinach</li>
        <li>Rice</li>
        <li>Birthday Cake</li>
        <li>Candles</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
````

My CSS

```
 .done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

My Javascript

```
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var ulclass = document.getElementsByClassName("noteList");

ul.style.background = "blue";
```

The weird thing is, when I use ul.style the background turns blue, when I use the class form ulclass.style, I get an script.js:35 ''Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined'' error.

Any way to get around that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the elements using `querySelectorAll()` and loop through them to attach event (*click*) to all the elements. Inside the event handler function you can toggle the class (*done*).

**Demo:**

```js
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var ulclass = document.querySelectorAll(".noteList");
ulclass.forEach(function(li){
  li.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.target.classList.toggle('done');    
    //or if you want to add the class
    //e.target.classList.add('done');    
  });
});
ul.style.background = "blue";
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<h1>Shopping List</h1>
<p id="first">Get it done today</p>
<input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
<button id="enter">Enter</button>
<ul class="noteList">
  <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
  <li>Jello</li>
  <li>Spinach</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Birthday Cake</li>
  <li>Candles</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ulclass` is not working because it is a list and not a single object. You have to loop through the list.

```
for(var i =0;i<ulclass.length;i++){
    ulclass[i].style.background = "blue";
}
```

Regarding the hover. you need to use `addEventListener` with the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns HTMLCollection, not an html element, so you need to pick the right element from this HTMLCollection in order to set the background color.
In your case:

```
var ulclass = document.getElementsByClassName("noteList");
ulclass[0].style.background = "blue";
```